# ps with custom output and separators

Tags: bash, debian, ps

I get a list of running processes with a custom separator (;;;).

```
ps -o "%p ;;; %a"
```

Output normally is like this:

```
    PID ;;;  COMMAND
  28819 ;;;  bash
  29752 ;;;  ps -o %p xxx  %a
```

This is not working anymore in Debian 12. Even if I set different separators it fails.

```
ps -o "%p xyz %a"
```

Error-message (in German):

```
Fehler: ungültiger AIX-Felddeskriptor

Aufruf: 
 ps [Optionen]

 Versuchen Sie »ps --Hilfe <Einfach|Liste|Ausgabe|Threads|Verschiedenes|Alle>«
  oder »ps --Hilfe <s|l|o|t|m|a>«,
 um zusätzliche Hilfe anzuzeigen.

Für weitere Informationen siehe ps(1).
```

- Debian 12: ps of procps-ng 4.0.2
- Debian 11: ps of procps-ng 3.3.17

Any ideas how I get custom separators in Debian 12??

Comment: So, how does it fail?

Comment: I believe I'm correct in that this is a duplicate. If this turns out to be totally unrelated (which I doubt), then leave a comment and explain why, and we'll open it again.